# One modal with different button id assign from sql

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently doing a final project for my school in online web programming but I'm having difficulties assign specific id from sql to button id, then open them with only one modal... Here's my coding:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SICT ADMIN NEW</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="admin">Admin | <a href="index.php">Log Out</a></div>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li><a href="Admin_Index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="Admin_New.php">New</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
<li class="icon">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onClick="myFunction()">☰</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
<div id="link_row">
<div id="link_row_1"><a href="Admin_New.php" style="color:black">New</a> >> <span style="color:#900">Campus</span></div>
<div id="link_row_2">
<div id="link_row_2_text"><button id="Add" ><a href="Admin_New_Campus.php">Add</a></button></div>
<div id="link_row_2_img"><img src="img/add_icon.png" width="15" height="15" alt="add"></div>
</div>
</div>

<table width="87%" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="17%">Campus_ID</th>
<th width="39%">Campus_Name</th>
<th width="38%">Location</th>
<th width="3%"></th>
<th width="5%"></th>
</tr>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "SICT";

//Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Campus_Record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Campus");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Campus_Record))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Campus_ID'] . "</td>";
$Campus_ID = $row['Campus_ID'];
$Temp = $row['Campus_ID'];
$Edit = $row['Campus_ID'];
echo "<td>" . $row['Campus_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><button id='$Edit'>Edit</button></td>";
echo "<td><a href='Admin_New_Campus_Delete.php?Campus_ID=$Campus_ID' onclick='return confirm(\"Confirm Delete Record?\")'><button id='Campus_ID'>Delete</button></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?> 
</table>

</div> 
<div id="footer">© 2017 Institute ofTechnical Education. · Privacy · Terms</div>


<div id="Campus_Modal" class="Modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="Close">&times;</span>
<form method = "post">
<div id="Modal_Content">
  Campus ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Campus_ID_2" required /><br><br>
  Campus Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Campus_Name_2" required /><br><br>
  Location:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Location_2" required /><br><br>
  <input type='text' id = "hidden" name="Temp" value = "<?php echo $Temp; ?>">
<div id="Submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" formaction ="Admin_New_Campus_Update.php" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
}

var modal = document.getElementById('Campus_Modal');
var btn = document.getElementById("Edit");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("Close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you are using different- different variable for same id? you can access one variable in all places

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways by which you can solve your issue:

1) you need to put your modal code into while loop.

2) If you want to have single modal, then you need to bind campus data in modal dynamically at the time of modal open.So below I have updated your code to make hidden field "campus id" dynamic whenever user clicks on edit button from the campus listing table:[code]By this way you need to bind other form data of modal as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SICT ADMIN NEW</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="admin">Admin | <a href="index.php">Log Out</a></div>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li><a href="Admin_Index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="Admin_New.php">New</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
<li class="icon">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onClick="myFunction()">☰</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
<div id="link_row">
<div id="link_row_1"><a href="Admin_New.php" style="color:black">New</a> >> <span style="color:#900">Campus</span></div>
<div id="link_row_2">
<div id="link_row_2_text"><button id="Add" ><a href="Admin_New_Campus.php">Add</a></button></div>
<div id="link_row_2_img"><img src="img/add_icon.png" width="15" height="15" alt="add"></div>
</div>
</div>

<table width="87%" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="17%">Campus_ID</th>
<th width="39%">Campus_Name</th>
<th width="38%">Location</th>
<th width="3%"></th>
<th width="5%"></th>
</tr>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "SICT";

//Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Campus_Record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Campus");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Campus_Record))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Campus_ID'] . "</td>";
  $Campus_ID = $row['Campus_ID'];
  $Temp = $row['Campus_ID'];
  $Edit = $row['Campus_ID'];
  echo "<td>" . $row['Campus_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><button id='$Edit' onclick ='reply_click(this);'>Edit</button></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='Admin_New_Campus_Delete.php?Campus_ID=$Campus_ID' onclick='return confirm(\"Confirm Delete Record?\")'><button id='Campus_ID'>Delete</button></a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?> 
</table>

</div> 
<div id="footer">© 2017 Institute ofTechnical Education. · Privacy · Terms</div>


<div id="Campus_Modal" class="Modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="Close">&times;</span>
<form method = "post">
<div id="Modal_Content">
  Campus ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Campus_ID_2" required /><br><br>
  Campus Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Campus_Name_2" required /><br><br>
  Location:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Location_2" required /><br><br>
  <input type='text' id = "hidden" name="Temp" value = "">
<div id="Submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" formaction ="Admin_New_Campus_Update.php" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
}

var modal = document.getElementById('Campus_Modal');
var btn = document.getElementById("Edit");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("Close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

function reply_click(obj)
{
  var test = obj.id;
  document.getElementById("hidden").value = test;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By this way you need to bind other form data of modal as well.
Add Comment